# How can I identify if a directory is a symbolic link (in contrast to a "real" local directory)?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, network-drive, mklink

I need to block access to network based directories. However by using tools like "mklink" users can create mapped directories which appear like local directories. I use a .net based code to get the UNC paths of the directories to identify network folders. But this does not work for mapped folders. Is there any information in `DirectoryInfo` class which I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested symlinks on a network drive - don't have permission to create one. I'll try at home later and update my answer.
But I can tell you that on a local disk:

- For a "normal" directory, the `Attributes` property will have the `Directory` bit set.
- For a symlink -- I'm guessing for a junction as well -- the `Directory` and `ReparsePoint` bits are set.

So try checking the `ReparsePoint` bit.

UPDATE:
A network folder has only the `Directory` bit set.
There seems to be some oddness about the root directory on a volume -- whether it's a local or network drive -- it also has the `Hidden` and `System` bits set.  Not sure why.
But it does seem that network folders behave just like local folders (which makes sense).